# Java JQuery javascript Galleria IO

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, zk, galleria

i have a serie of galleries using `Galleria IO` plugin over `JQuery` using `Zk Framework` i load the galleries when i enter fullscreen mode everything is smoothly the problem arises when i reload the galleria using the same code when i load the galleria the first time. and when i click on the galleria the galleria enters in fullscreen mode but the size of the galleria is the same in the normal view and the sizes of the images is the same as the normal view this issue is in `Chrome` in `Mozilla` works perfect...

here is the code i am using to enter full screen mode..

```
Galleria.run('#galleriaID',{extend:function()
{
  var gallery=this;gallery.attachKeyboard({left:gallery.prev,right:gallery.next,});
  $('#fullScreenMode').click(function(event)    
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    gallery.enterFullscreen();
  });
 }});
```

[image: FirstTime page loads..]
[image: After reload the galleria]
i hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
  Galleria.configure({trueFullscreen:false});
  Galleria.ready(function(){this.enterFullscreen();});
```